# Oracle - I can't create and use a synonym in the same script?

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, synonym

I have a script in SQL Developer where I (want to) CREATE OR REPLACE a synonym, use the synonym in a SELECT, and then DROP the synonym (cleaning up after myself).

But if the synonym doesn't already exist when I run the script, I get an error "table or view does not exist" and the script won't run.  If I create the synonym separately so that it exist when I run the script, the script compiles and runs OK.   The synonym gets replaced, used and deleted just fine.  But then I can't run the script any more.

So... the compiler is smart enough to know that the 'table or view' doesn't exist, but not smart enough to know that the script itself creates a synonym.

Is there a way around this??

I created a table:

```
CREATE TABLE X (COLUMNA VARCHAR(10), COLUMNB VARCHAR(10));
```

I insert some data:

```
INSERT INTO X(COLUMNA, COLUMNB) VALUES ('HELLO','WORLD');
```

When I run this in a block:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM TESTSYN1 FOR X;
SELECT * FROM testsyn1;
DROP SYNONYM testsyn1;
```

I get 'table or view does not exist' on the SELECT statement. If I highlight and run the CREATE by itself, then highlight and run the SELECT by itself, then highlight and run the DROP by itself, it's all good. I just can't run them together.

Comment: What kind of script - just a series of SQL statements? Or are you creating and dropping the synonym inside a PL/SQL block dynamically, and trying to refer to it statically inside the same block? It would be helpful to include an example of what you are doing in your question (simplified, as long as it shows the relevant context).

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Fine. So, where is it?

Comment: I created a table:

    CREATE TABLE X
    (COLUMNA VARCHAR(10), COLUMNB VARCHAR(10));

I insert some data:
    INSERT INTO X(COLUMNA, COLUMNB)
    VALUES ('HELLO','WORLD');

When I run this:

    CREATE OR REPLACE SYNONYM TESTSYN1 FOR X;
    SELECT * FROM X;
     DROP SYNONYM X;

I get 'table or view does not exist' on the SELECT statement.  If I highlight and run the CREATE by itself, then highlight and run the SELECT by itself, then highlight and run the DROP by itself, it's all good.  I just can't run them together.

Comment: sorry about the earlier 'comment'.. still getting used to using this thing.. must... not... hit... RETURN... :)

Comment: @AS400Jockey - you can delete both of your last two comments since you've added the code to the question now.

Comment: I'm still not sure exactly what you're doing. A block usually refers to a PL/SQL block, but you don't seem to be using PL/SQL (you can't create/drop with static SQL in a PL/SQL block). Are you selecting/highlighting the three statements and doing 'run statement', rather than 'run script' (with or without selecting those lines)? Either works fine in the current version, but I'm wondering if you're using a old version that has a quirk with run-statement. Which version of SQL Developer are you using? I'm not sure why you have the synonym, but that's not really the issue...